# I want to return a 410 from NextResponse in middleware

Tags: next.js

So what I would like to do is to do the following

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const { pathname } = request.nextUrl.clone();
    if(pathname.includes("some text")}{
    return NextResponse.respond("", {status: 410, mime: "application/text"!});
}
```

where the NextResponse.respond does not rewrite or redirect the url but responds to it directly.

why do I want this - well I noticed there were a number of urls that were being requested that were no longer ever going to be found on our sites and it made sense to just say hey those urls are gone permanently 410, and here is an empty response in stead of going all the way to the page building level that goes ahead and gets content and does a bunch of requests and returns 8kb of data with links to css, js etc. for a request that will never be found.

If it cannot be done this way how do I do it?